# Node app deployment on ZEIT(NOW) - gets 502 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, vercel

I have on node app working in development environment. Here is my project structure

```
-dist
-src
package.json
now.json
```

`src` folder is main source code contains server script `index.ts` . `dist` is compiled js files.

Here is my `now` conifiguration

```
{
    "build": {
        "env": {
            ....
        }
    },
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "dist/index.js",
            "use": "@now/node-server"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/",
            "dest": "dist/index.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Anything on `/_src` and the "Functions" tab?

Comment: Yes I can see all my directory structure in source tab and function also.

Comment: But anything in the runtime logs (functions tab)?

Comment: In runtime log I see error as log files are not found to write log but log folder and files are there in source tab.